# Nav not collapsing when a NavItem is selected on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, react-router-dom, react-router-bootstrap

I'm building a navbar that is expected to be responsive when it switches to mobile devices. In other words, collapse when mobile, then when the navitems are selected / clicked, it should route to the path and collapse all navitems to a toggle-style bar. However, below a snapshot of what I got and it's associated code:

[image: About Us link selected / clicked but all navitems are still on the about us page]

CODE:

```
render() {
return (
  !this.state.isAuthenticating &&
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand>
         <LinkContainer to="/">
           <a>
           <img src={logo} alt="logo" height="70" width="75"/>
           <p>hybriData</p>
           </a>
         </LinkContainer>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
      </Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav pullRight>
          {this.state.isAuthenticated
            ? <Fragment>
                <LinkContainer to="/settings">
                  <NavItem>Settings</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</NavItem>
              </Fragment>
            : <Fragment>
                <LinkContainer to="/About Us">
                <NavItem eventKey={2}>About Us</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to="/Contact">
                  <NavItem eventKey={3}>Contact</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to="/works">
                  <NavItem eventKey={5}>Works</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to="/signin">
                  <NavItem eventKey={6}>SignIn</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
              </Fragment>
          }
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also integrated some of this solution [react-bootstrap how to collapse menu when item is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452695/react-bootstrap-how-to-collapse-menu-when-item-is-selected) using the expanded and onSelect props of the navbar and nav's activeKey and onSelect props to achieve desired functionality but to no fruition. How can I implement desired functionality of having all navitem's collapsed when any path(s) is navigated to , clicked / selected? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/64lyyz247r). It's about the **order of items**. If you look at the [bootstrap CSS](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css), you see some styles like

```
.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}}
```

The > symbol is a selector that selects all immediate descendants or children (first 'wrap layer' only, not applied to second 'wrap layer'), namely if you have

```
<ul class="nav">
 <div>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
 </div>
</ul>
```

the styles are **not applied**, while

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li>something</li>
 <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

works. In your case, try replacing the `<Fragment>` with `<Nav>` and remove the outer `<Nav>`.

Another part you may want to modify is the LinkContainer wrapping the NavItem part. Usually we have `<li>` (NavItem) wrapping `<a>` (Link) but not the other way round.

Although react-bootstrap makes the code easier to read, it abstracts the details and may be harder to get something working. If you have difficulty with react-bootstrap, I suggest you to stick with pure bootstrap elements. The codes are slightly longer but the appearance is the same. You can follow [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) to use bootstrap styles.

Comment: @Imathl, your recommendations worked. I appreciate your detailed explanations and references to what happens under the hood with already abstracted react-bootstrap components. Thank you much!

Comment: I thought I also point out that LinkContainer is being used to resolve invalid dom nesting error that arises when you use react-bootstrap with react-router